# Creating a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to set up a bootstrap modal so every time the user clicks on a circle (button) a modal pops up showing content related to that circle.

However, when the user clicks on a circle I don't see anything - I don't see the modal opening. And I can't figure out where I'm going wrong..

Below is my code.

```
.header {
background-color:LightBlue;
padding:20px;
text-align:center;
}

#circleRed {
background: Red;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}

#circleGreen {
background: Lime;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
border-radius: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}

.modal{
display: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
padding-top: 100px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content{
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}

.close-button {
color: #aaaaaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close-button:hover {
background-color: darkgray;
}

.close-button:focus {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<?php

require_once 'Net/SSH2.php';
require_once 'phpseclib1.0.10/Crypt/RSA.php';
$config = require 'config.json';
$log = 'logfile.txt';

if (is_array($config)) {
    foreach ($config as $key => $cred) {
        $ssh = new Net_SSH2($cred['ip'], $cred['port']);
        $key = new Crypt_RSA();
        $key->loadKey($cred['key']);

        echo($cred['name']); //get Raspberry PI name from config file

        if (!$ssh->login('pi', $key)) {
            file_put_contents($log, "[" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "]Login Failed for {$cred['ip']}\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            continue;
        }

        $output = $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');
        $array = explode(',', $output);

        if (end($array) >= 0) { ?>
            <!-- trigger modal with button -->
            <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=<? "#myModal'. $key. '" ?></div>

                <!-- modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labeledby= <? "exampleModalLabel'. $key. '" ?> aria="hidden">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"

                    <!-- modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Location: <? $cred['name']; ?></h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                            <p>Currently Playing: <? $array[1]; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else {
            echo '<div id="circleRed" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target= "#myModal' . $key . '"</div>';
            //echo '<p>Issues: '.$array[2].'</p>';
        };
    }
};
?>
```

**Update - below is my rendered HTML page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<title>Raspberry PI Dashboard</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 

</head>
<body style="height:1500px">
<div class="header">

<h1>Dashboard</h1>

</div>
<style>

    .header {
    background-color:LightBlue;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #circleRed {
    background: Red;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

   #circleGreen {
   background: Lime;
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   }

   .modal{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   }
   
   .modal-content{
   background-color: #fefefe;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   width: 80%;
   }
   
   .close-button {
   color: #aaaaaa;
   float: right;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
   }
   
   .close-button:hover {
   background-color: darkgray;
   }
   
   .close-button:focus {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
  
   
</style>
Guildford Test     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBKeKIiH2X0V8aYu5Jhg+…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBK…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBKeK…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBKe….
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Guildford Test </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: nm_003.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Burton on Trent     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46ZchPlz19…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46ZchPlz…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46Zch…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46ZchPlz19u…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Burton on Trent </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: eurochange.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Woking     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYlBGSvZ….
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYlB…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYlB…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYlBGS….
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Woking </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: eurochange.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Staines     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcU…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcUjbFJNAd….
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcUjbF…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcUjbFJ…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Staines </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: eurochange.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Swindon     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2Ho…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2HocsgC..
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2Hoc…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2Hocsg…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Swindon </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       


</body></html>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
<title>Raspberry PI Dashboard</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"> 

</head>
<body style="height:1500px">
<div class="header">

<h1>Dashboard</h1>

</div>
<style>

    .header {
    background-color:LightBlue;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    }

    #circleRed {
    background: Red;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

   #circleGreen {
   background: Lime;
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   }

   .modal{
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   padding-top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   }
   
   .modal-content{
   background-color: #fefefe;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #888;
   width: 80%;
   }
   
   .close-button {
   color: #aaaaaa;
   float: right;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: bold;
   }
   
   .close-button:hover {
   background-color: darkgray;
   }
   
   .close-button:focus {
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
  
   
</style>
Guildford Test     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCI...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBK...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBKeK…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAzn5X9JCICFBKe…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Guildford Test </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: nm_003.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Burton on Trent     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46ZchPlz1…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46ZchPlz19u…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAtHjHL46ZchPlz…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Burton on Trent </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: eurochange.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Woking     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pY…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYlBGSv…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYlBG…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAzwZB3pYl…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Woking </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: eurochange.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Staines     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOC…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcUj…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcU…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEA58vxOCVcUjbFJ…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Staines </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: eurochange.h264</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       Swindon     <!-- trigger modal with button here -->
    <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2HocsgCQ…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" <="" div="">

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2Hoc…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2Hocs…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

            <!-- modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKgIBAAKCAgEAuUlPw2Hocs…
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----">Location: Swindon </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                    <p>Currently Playing: </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       


</body></html>
```

**And the changes I made to the code:**

```
if(is_array($config)){
$num = 0;

foreach($config as $num => $cred){
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($cred['ip'], $cred['port']);
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey($cred['key']);

echo ($cred['name']); //get PI name from config file

if (!$ssh->login('pi', $key)){
file_put_contents($log, "[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."]Login Failed for {$cred['ip']}\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
continue;
$num++; }
```

Comment: Seriously? How many times are you going to ask the same question? [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407465/bootstrap-modal-does-not-open-on-button-trigger), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50410118/all-modals-show-the-same-content-when-triggered-via-a-button-click) and three is this one.

Comment: And btw, you still have an unclosed tag in your code. (`<div class="modal-dialog" role="document"`)

Comment: Until I have a working solution/ or figure out what I'm doing. I still cannot open a modal, your advice with separating from PHP to HTML was helpful and I've taken that on board but it did not help my main problem.

Comment: Ok ok, don't get angry. I'm only trying to help you :) Take a look at my answer. I think it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED answer entirely

Here is a quick fix that will work

```
<?php

require_once 'Net/SSH2.php';
require_once 'phpseclib1.0.10/Crypt/RSA.php';
$config = require 'config.json';
$log = 'logfile.txt';

$num = 0;
if (is_array($config)) {
    foreach ($config as $cred) {
        $ssh = new Net_SSH2($cred['ip'], $cred['port']);
        $key = new Crypt_RSA();
        $key->loadKey($cred['key']);

        echo($cred['name']); //get Raspberry PI name from config file

        if (!$ssh->login('pi', $key)) {
            file_put_contents($log, "[" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "]Login Failed for {$cred['ip']}\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
            continue;
        }

        $output = $ssh->exec('tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv');
        $array = explode(',', $output);

        if (end($array) >= 0) { ?>
            <!-- trigger modal with button -->
            <div id="circleGreen" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?= $num; ?>"></div>

                <!-- modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?= $num; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel<?= $num; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                    <!-- modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel<?= $num; ?>">Location: <? $cred['name']; ?></h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>No issues currently reported.</p>
                            <p>Currently Playing: <?= $array[1]; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else {
            echo '<div id="circleRed" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal' . $num . '"</div>';
            //echo '<p>Issues: '.$array[2].'</p>';
        }
        $num++;
    }
};
?>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for clarifying and for the example, but I still can't open a modal with you code :( Using your code I've been reading up content/ examples all day to see what I might be doing wrong.. but I'm still not sure

Comment: @Sara please attach rendered html. You can copy it using devtools, right click on element, and choose 'Copy -> Copy outerHTML'

Comment: I've updated my question to show the rendered html. I took out some of the RSA key bit to make the code easier for you to read

Comment: Haha I think you're right.. the universe just hates me. I created the variable and changed my for loop but that hasn't worked. I'll update my question with the updated code.

Comment: @Sara Well it looks like you did not change `$key` variable to `$num`. You can forget about `$key` it is a solution that did not work. Just throw it out (`foreach ($config as $cred) {...}`)

Comment: @Sara ok I have to agree that it was a little bit my fault but I did not see, that inside your loop you create variable `$key` so using it in `foreach` loop was pointless since you were overriding it anyway. Duh :) Ok, so just do the trick with `$num` and it will work properly :)

Comment: Hallelujah!!! It works I can open the modal and see the content now.. thank you so much for your support!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#YourModalID"` to your trigger button. Your modal's main div should have the same ID as the data-target on your trigger button.

For example:

```
<!--My trigger button-->
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>

<!--My login's modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" aria-hidden="true">
   <!-- My modal's content -->
</div>
```

You can read extra info in bootstrap's website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Her data-target isn't defined.